# How to add columns dynamically in slickgrid?

Tags: javascript, freemarker, slickgrid

I'm trying to add dynamic columns to slickgrid by iterating through javascript array object.

The format for object in js array is:

```
 auditor = {"firstName":"test audit manager","lastName":".","middleName":null,"partyId":"11140"}

var columns = [];
/*from the ajax result, I'm obtaining 'auditors' js array */

for (var key in auditors) {

var auditor =  auditors[key];
                    var name = auditor["firstName"];

                    if(auditor["middleName"]){
                        name += auditor["middleName"];
                    }
                    if(auditor["lastName"]){
                        name += auditor["lastName"];
                    }
                    if(auditors[parseInt(key)+parseInt(1)]){
                        columns = columns += '{id: '+'"auditor_'+key+'", name: '+'"'+name+'"'+', field: '+'"auditor_'+key+'", editor: Slick.Editors.Text, width:80, minWidth:80, sortable:true, focusable:false},'; 
                    }
                    else{
                        columns = columns += '{id: '+'"auditor_'+key+'", name: '+'"'+name+'"'+', field: '+'"auditor_'+key+'", editor: Slick.Editors.Text, width:80, minWidth:80, sortable:true, focusable:false}';
                    }
                }//end for loop

columns.replace(/\\\//g, "/");

var options = {
                enableCellNavigation: true,
                enableColumnReorder: false,
                editable: true,       
                forceFitColumns: false,         
                enableCellNavigation: true,
                //enableAddRow: true,
                asyncEditorLoading: false,          
                autoEdit: true,
                secondaryHeaderRowHeight: 25
            };

            $(function () {
                grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
                grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.CellSelectionModel()); 
                var columnpicker = new Slick.Controls.ColumnPicker(columns, grid, options);

                grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                    var item = args.item;   
                    grid.invalidateRow(data.length);
                    data.push(item);
                    grid.updateRowCount();
                    grid.render();
                });
            });
```

Comment: With the above code I'm getting undefined 'rows' and 'columns' added. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly declaring `columns` as an array at the top, but then you are adding string values to it later on.  Use `.push` to add an element to an array, and the values should not be strings.

Something like:

```
columns.push(
  { 
    id: "auditor_" + key, 
    name: name, 
    field: "auditor_"+ key, 
    editor: Slick.Editors.Text, 
    width:80,  
    minWidth:80,  
    sortable:true, 
    focusable:false
  }
);
```

Then clearly your `.replace()` will have to be done on an element of the array, or before assigning value to the array.